# get all occurence with findall in python

Tags: python, regex, findall

I need to get "relay.albacom.net" and "smtp.albacom.net"

```
import re

string="""<tr bgcolor="#d3ebf8"><td>Albacom</td><td>relay.albacom.net</td><td></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#d3ebf8"><td>Albacom</td><td>smtp.albacom.net</td><td></td></tr>"""

test=re.findall(r'<tr bgcolor="#d3ebf8"><td>.*</td><td>(.*)</td><td>.*</td></tr>', string)

print test
```

However, I only get `['smtp.albacom.net']`.

The following `.*` means any character right? So it should work...

Thx !

Comment: It is correct output, look [here](https://regex101.com/r/nU3oX0/1). The point is that the first `.*` will match the whole string, and then the pattern expects only 1 TD after the capturing group. Thus, you get the contents of the last but one cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Non-greedy selector:

```
<tr bgcolor="#d3ebf8"><td>.*?</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>.*?</td></tr>
```

When you use `.*` without `?` regex try to capture as much character as it can for this expression. but adding a `?`, force it to select as little as it can.

[Check this sample](https://regex101.com/r/oS9wL9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
test = re.findall('[a-z]+\.albacom\.[a-z]+',string)
```

I believe this should allow you to find the items in a string which are of the form **.albacom.** in a more generalized way.

Comment: He doesn't know the URLs will contain `.albacom.`, those are just examples.  He's searching for them based on where they are in the document.

Comment: how did you figure that out from the description provided?

Comment: Notice how his regex contains lots of HTML. but he doesn't try to describe the URL at all.  That part's just `(.*)`.  Particularly telling is the `bgcolor="#d3ebf8"` part.  That's how he identifies the section of HTML that contains the information he wants.  It's a typical screen-scraping tactic.